# ajax image viewer , back button and history - missing html and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-history

I am playing with jquery and js, trying to build an ajax overlay image viewer for a PHP website. With this code included at the bottom of the 'gallery page', the viewer opens and i can navigate with next and previous links inside the viewer. But the back button and the history is hard to understand. The browser often shows **only the response of the ajax call**, without the underlying page and css files, after some clicks back.

Perhaps somebody knows what is generally happening in such a case? I would like to understand why *back* sometimes results in a broken page, i.e. only the ajax response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function loadOverlay(href) {
            $.ajax({
                    url: href,
                })
                .done(function( data ) {
                    var theoverlay = $('#flvr_overlay');
                    theoverlay.html( data );

                    var zoompic = $('#zoompic');

                    zoompic.load(function() {
                        var nih = zoompic.prop('naturalHeight');
                        var photobox = $('#photobox');
                        if($(window).width() >= 750){
                            photobox.css('height',nih);
                        }
                        theoverlay.show();
                        $('body').css('overflow-y','hidden');

                        $(window).resize(function () {
                            var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
                            if (viewportWidth < 750) {
                                photobox.css('height','auto');
                                zoompic.removeClass('translatecenter');
                            }else{
                                photobox.css('height',nih);
                                zoompic.addClass('translatecenter');
                            }
                        });
                    });
            });
            return false;
        }

        var inithref = window.location.href;

        $(window).on('popstate', function (e) {
            if (e.originalEvent.state !== null) {
                //load next/previous
                loadOverlay(location.href);
            } else {
                //close overlay
                $('#flvr_overlay').hide().empty();
                $('body').css('overflow-y','scroll');
                history.replaceState(null, inithref, inithref);
            }
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.overlay', function () {
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            history.pushState({}, href, href);    
            loadOverlay(href);
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

### edit

clicking *forward* works:

1. /photos (normal page)
2. /photos/123 (overlay with '/photos' below)
3. /locations/x (normal page)
4. /photos/567 (overlay with '/locations/x' below)

clicking *back* gives me the broken view at point 2.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to prevent the default behaviour in your popstate to prevent the browser from actually navigating back to the previous page?

Comment: hm. I have added it, but did not help. The problem occurs when clicking back button. When all overlays are clicked back, the original page appears. And when I then click back again, the previous overlay is loaded, but not it's previous, underlying page. So it would be better to load the previous page without the overlay in this case.

Comment: Consider checking out a client-side routing library - I really like Sammy.js. It helps a lot with changing of URLs, back button management, etc. There are others, which I haven't used, like history.js, jquery-bbq, and many more

Answer (score 0):

you have to manage it by own code.

You have a few options.

1. Use localstorage to remember the last query
2. Use cookies (but don't)

Use the hash as you tried with document.location.hash = "last search" to update the url. You would look at the hash again and if it is set then do another ajax to populate the data. If you had done localstorage then you could just cache the last ajax request.

I would go with the localstorage and the hash solution because that's what some websites do. You can also copy and paste a URL and it will just load the same query. This is pretty nice and I would say very accessible

Changing to document.location.hash = "latest search" didn't change anything.t.

This goes into the rest of the jQuery code:

```
// Replace the search result table on load.
if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
    if ('myTable' in localStorage && window.location.hash) {
        $("#myTable").html(localStorage.getItem('myTable'));
    }
}

// Save the search result table when leaving the page.
$(window).unload(function () {
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
        var form = $("#myTable").html();
        localStorage.setItem('myTable', form);
    }
});
```

Comment: "as you tried with document.location.hash" ? could it be you answered this on the wrong question?

Comment: like if the url has http://code.shouttoday.com#ajax1 then ajax1 by  conditionally called from code

Comment: ok i will try this. i like how it works on facebook, but does not seem to be that easy

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is that use INPUT fields to preserved while using back button. So, I do like that :

My page contains an input hidden like that :

Once ajax content is dynamicaly loaded, I backup content into my hidden field before displaying it:

```
function loadAlaxContent()
{
    var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
            //prepare ajax request
            // ...
        }).done( function(htmlData) {
            // save content
            $('#bfCache').val( $('#bfCache').val() + htmlData);

            // display it
            displayAjaxContent(htmlData);
        });
}
```

And last thing to do is to test the hidden field value at page loading. If it contains something, that because the back button has been used, so, we just have to display it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    htmlData = $('#bfCache').val();

    if(htmlData)
        displayAjaxContent( htmlData );
});
```